# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The property 'options.family' must be one of: 0, 4, 6. Received false

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, binance

When using the `node-binance-api`, namely the order book, this error appears. I don't know how to solve it. Experience is not enough...

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The property 'options.family' must be one of: 0, 4, 6. Received false
        at lookup (node:dns:143:7)
        at node:net:1082:5
        at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (node:internal/async_hooks:463:18)
        at lookupAndConnect (node:net:1081:3)
        at Socket.connect (node:net:1019:5)
        at Object.connect (node:_tls_wrap:1660:13)
        at Agent.createConnection (node:https:142:22)
        at Agent.createSocket (node:_http_agent:343:26)
        at Agent.addRequest (node:_http_agent:294:10)
        at new ClientRequest (node:_http_client:311:16) {
      code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE'
    }
    
    Node.js v18.0.0
```

[code that doesn't work](https://github.com/jaggedsoft/node-binance-api#maintain-market-depth-cache-locally-via-websocket)

On the previous version, node js was running, but also with an error. However, it worked.

```
(node:6424) [DEP0153] DeprecationWarning: Type coercion of dns.lookup options is deprecated
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Comment: As far as I understand , it is related to this
https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback

Comment: https://github.com/jaggedsoft/node-binance-api/issues/819

Answer (score 9):

Following Oleg's links from the question comments, the solution is now stated here: [link](https://github.com/jaggedsoft/node-binance-api/issues/819#issuecomment-1242904189)

In short, Node 18 deprectaited `dns.lookup` and `dnsPromises.lookup` options type coercion. [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V18.md#18.0.0)

The IP address version needs to be stated when creating an authorized binance object. The option default is false, that is incompatible with Node 18's dns lookup.

```
const binance = new Binance().options({
  APIKEY: '<YOUR-APIKEY>',
  APISECRET: '<YOUR-APISECRET>',
  'family': 4,
});
```

And from the node [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback):

"family  |  The record family. Must be 4, 6, or 0. For backward compatibility reasons,'IPv4' and 'IPv6' are interpreted as 4 and 6 respectively. The value 0 indicates that IPv4 and IPv6 addresses are both returned. Default: 0"

Comment: works for me thanks